# Is it possible to toggle different divs by clicking on different elements using the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Say I have 50 `div`, like this:

```
    <div class="btn1"></div> //Toggles the first container to appear
    <div class="btn2"></div> //Toggles the second container to appear
    <div class="btn3"></div> //Toggles the third container to appear
```

And another 50 `div` that contain information, like this:

```
    <div class="container-1"><h1>This is the first container</h1></div>
    <div class="container-2"><h1>This is the second container</h1></div>
    <div class="container-3"><h1>This is the third container</h1></div>
```

Is it possible to make the corresponding `div` toggle when each button is clicked with just one function? I have read a little about delegation and operating on parents/siblings but it only seems to work on multiple buttons opening the same container, rather than each button opening each container.

Somehow I don't think writing a function for every div is the way to go.

Comment: `is it possible to make the corresponding divs toggle when each button is clicked with just one function?` - Yes. Bind to the `btn` `'click'` event using jQuery `on()` (or similar) and then can either use parsing to get the number from the class in `btn` to target the matching `container` or add a data attribute to each div matching them like `data-id="1"` or use positional selectors, like `siblings` or similar if the `container` div is always in the same position from the `btn` div etc... Pick one, try & Try it out. If you get issues, post your code and we can help.

Comment: mind to comment why the downvote on all the solutions provided here??

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I didn't. I refreshed the page and they were all downvoted - no Idea why,  2 users were very helpful.

Comment: @J.Daykin my comment was intended for the person who down voted.. it just gets frustrating when someone down votes without explaining the reason for it.. as far as I see all the solutions work... its just each one has their own way of doing it..

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Sorry, Yes I totally agree. That's the beauty of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible. Basically you need to add a reference to clicked object so click event will know what to show/hide

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var $dataTarget = $($(this).data('target'));
    $dataTarget.show().siblings('.container').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn1" data-target=".container-1"></div> //Toggles the first container to appear
<div class="btn btn2" data-target=".container-2"></div> //Toggles the second container to appear
<div class="btn btn3" data-target=".container-3"></div> //Toggles the third container to appear


<div class="container container-1">
  <h1>This is the first container</h1>
</div>
<div class="container container-2">
  <h1>This is the second container</h1>
</div>
<div class="container container-3">
  <h1>This is the third container</h1>
</div>
```

This will show the container targeted, then will hide other containers.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use starts with selector `^` [Document here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
2. Use `data-*` to store corresponding div on button.
3. Select the `data-*` then use as selector to show

   ```js
     $('div[class^=container]').hide();
   $('div[class^=btn]').click(function() {
     $('div[class^=container]').hide();
     var thisclass = $(this).attr("data-class")
     $('.' + thisclass).show();
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="btn1" data-class="container-1">1</div> 
   <div class="btn2" data-class="container-2">2</div> 
   <div class="btn3" data-class="container-3">3</div>

   <div class="container-1">
     <h1>This is the first container</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-2">
     <h1>This is the second container</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-3">
     <h1>This is the third container</h1>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `index` and `eq` to do this

```js
$("[class*='btn']").click(function(){
 $("[class*='container-']").eq($(this).index()-1).toggle();
})
```

```css
[class*="btn"]{
 width:150px;
 height:20px;
 border:2px solid #000;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn1"></div>
<div class="btn2"></div>
<div class="btn3"></div>

<div class="container-1">
    <h1>This is the first container</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
    <h1>This is the second container</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-3">
    <h1>This is the third container</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[class^='btn']").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var str = $(this)[0].className;
      $(".container-" + str.substring(3, str.length)).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

Find all the class which starts with `btn` and apply a click event to it..
and based on the number hide the corresponding container class.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[class^='btn']").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var str = $(this)[0].className;
      $(".container-" + str.substring(3, str.length)).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn1">aaaa</div> //Toggles the first container to appear
<div class="btn2">bbbb</div> //Toggles the second container to appear
<div class="btn3">cccc</div> //Toggles the third container to appear
<div class="container-1">
  <h1>This is the first container</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
  <h1>This is the second container</h1>
</div>
<div class="container-3">
  <h1>This is the third container</h1>
</div>
```

(Source: fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/17/)